# Can a secret URL be indexed by search engines?

Tags: security, search-engine, web-crawler

My boss recently came to me with a security concern.

My company does research and then sends a report to the client (this report is unique for each client and contains identifying information about their business).

We email the report to the client, but we also upload it to our server and provide the client a url containing a hash that he can use to access the report online at any time. (in other words, anyone with the link can access the report)
The link looks something like:

- http://www.our_website.com/report_page.php?33355-fn347rhwfh83j3f (just putting random string here is place of the hash)

The code behind the page does the following:

- explodes the hash and uses it to look up the report info in the database
- verifies that this hash is indeed valid according to report id and email
- retrieves the report pdf from the server and displays it.

If the hash in the url does not exist or is not valid, the user get an "invalid" message.

His question is:

> Clicking on the link opens the report, does this mean that Google can index these pages and they may appear in Google's search results for the whole world to see?

My gut feeling is that no, if a crawler would get to report_page.php, all it would see if the invalid message, unless it somehow had a valid hash, but I don't know this for sure, and after searching around, I didn't come up with anything to prove me right (or wrong).

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the URL is posted on a publically accessible page, then the Google crawlers will find it and the page will be indexed. From what you say, this sounds unlikely to be the case so you should be safe. If your client happens to make the URL public though, then Google will crawl and index it. It's similar to a password: keep it private and you're safe.

Comment: I think this is the case too. If the link is an html page, I think ensuring you don't include google analytics might not be a bad idea. I haven't anything to back-up whether that has an effect or not, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Jeremy - How does not including google analytics help? Is that the same as disallowing the crawler in robots.txt?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible for a web crawler to index such pages -- lots of websites use long opaque hashes to identify pages, that alone makes no difference with regards to search engines.

You need to have a robots.txt file disallowing access to those URLs, and add the appropriate headers and meta tags making it clear that crawlers should not index them.  Also, if it is really private data, the transaction should be encrypted with SSL.  You might also consider having the hashes be usable once only, i.e. require that a new hash be sent by email each time the customer wants to download it.  That would effectively prevent random drive-by crawlers (or people) from reading them. (although there is still a race condition between the time the email is sent and when the customer uses the enclosed hash)

Answer (score -1):

in robots.txt you can disallow google and other search engine index your url

by default search engine indexed your url if you link it any where

Comment: This is actually a very bad idea. It will keep legitimate search engines away, sure. But it will actually provide a nice list of private data for anyone else who doesn't check or obey the robots.txt file.

Comment: many hacks is from google search ;) search in net with something like this admin.php or other names ...